# How to change Laravel date format

Tags: php, laravel

$from_date_time = get_before_of_string(' - ', $request->date_range); //06/23/2021 12:00 AM
$to_date_time = get_after_of_string(' - ', $request->date_range); //06/23/2021 12:00 AM

$from_date_time = Carbon::parse($from_date_time)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //2021-06-24 14:30:00 this is DB format
$to_date_time = Carbon::parse($to_date_time)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //2021-06-24 14:30:00 this is DB format

Answer (score 0):

$from_date_time = get_before_of_string(' - ', $request->date_range); //06/23/2021 12:00 AM
$to_date_time = get_after_of_string(' - ', $request->date_range); //06/23/2021 12:00 AM

```
    $from_date_time = Carbon::parse($from_date_time)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //2021-06-24 14:30:00 this is DB format
    $to_date_time = Carbon::parse($to_date_time)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //2021-06-24 14:30:00 this is DB format
```